# "Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously” with Image Embed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, embed, flex4.5

> "Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously”

A search for this string in Google and on SO yields a ton of results. I have read tons of them, but none of them really talk about duplicated image assets when there is actually no duplicate files in the Package Explorer.

Using embed code in CSS files:

```
.helpLink {
    over-skin: Embed(source="images/blank.gif");
}
```

...and then importing said CSS files into mxml files:

```
<mx:Style source="skins/main.css" />
```

...I get 100's of errors like this:

```
Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously.
        _class_embed_css_images_blank_gif__1196752591_1370790129 (from       _class_embed_css_images_blank_gif__1196752591_1370790129.as) and
  Faces:_class_embed_css_images_blank_gif__1196752591_1370790129 (from Faces/_class_embed_css_images_blank_gif__1196752591_1370790129.as) are available.

  BriefInfoFace.mxml
  /[REDACTED]/src/Faces
```

This would imply that there is a `blank.gif` file in `Faces`, but I assure you there is not. It exists in only one place in my "Package Explorer", in the `images` folder which is a sibling to `Faces`. The Faces folder only has `mxml` files, and the images folder only has real image files (png, gif).

If I clean the project, It will compile and run, but any subsequent runs after that will not compile. This presents a huge problem because I have to continually clean the project every time I want to debug it. How can I prevent this error when there is no `blank.gif` in the Faces folder?

**UPDATE 7/14**

As requested, [here is a dump](https://gist.github.com/3113152) of the directory structure

**UPDATE 7/15**

As requested, here is a pic showing the places I pull in `main.css`
[image]
[image]

And the [imports](https://gist.github.com/3119721) found in `BriefInfoFace.mxml`

Comment: By any chance do you have the `-keep-generated-actionscript` compiler flag set to true?

Comment: Nope. Compiler settings are: -locale en_US -compatibility-version=3.0

Comment: If we add slashes to the sources, e.g. `source="/skins/main.css"`, will it work? Make your links explicit all the way to the project root.

Comment: This did not solve the problem either. Making them absolute paths still compiled, but the error message was the same (with the new paths)

Comment: You said /Faces and /images are siblings, what about /skins? Also, where is the mxml (which imports main.css) located?

Comment: I updated the question with a full deep listing of the src directory

Comment: Nothing unusual about the file structure as far as I can tell. How about duplicate import statements for main.css? Maybe one in the main application and one in a component inside `Faces`?

Please don't rant about drive-by douchery. The only people who will certainly receive your rant are concerned and potentially helpful strangers like me.

Comment: Updated the question. The only time I use main.css is in mx:Style lines like above: http://cloud.coneybeare.net/I68L

Comment: Is `TrialPopup` used inside `BriefInfoFace`?

Comment: Nope. Here are the imports found in that file: https://gist.github.com/3119721

Comment: Something about your namespace... man, I wished I were at your computer.

Comment: Just curious, do all your MXML components contain a reference to the CSS?

Comment: Nope, not all of them, just the ones specified in the screenshots above. You may be on to something... The files with the compilation errors are the ones that pull in the main.css file. Should I not be adding "<mx:Style source="skins/main.css" />" to all the files where I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is a better idea to leave non-code assets like images outside of src folder.  In my case, I would create an "asset" folder next to src folder and store my images there.

If that's not an option for your project, have you tried turning off incremental compile option by going to Project Properties -> Flex Compiler, and add -incremental=false in "Additional compiler arguments" text field.

Comment: -incremental=false did not work, nor did moving the images to the parent directory: Description Resource Path Location Type
Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. _class_embed_css____images_blank_gif__931497498_680344516 (from _class_embed_css____images_blank_gif__931497498_680344516.as) and Faces:_class_embed_css____images_blank_gif__931497498_680344516 (from Faces/_class_embed_css____images_blank_gif__931497498_680344516.as) are available. BriefInfoFace.mxml /[REDACTED]/src/Faces Unknown Flex Problem

Comment: If you could provided some project source code, I would be more than happy to take a crack at your issue.